# Is there something like a jasmine `toNotContain` acceptance criteria for tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

*Jasmin comes with many functions for checking the expected values for validating specifications and tests.*

Is there besides

```
getJasmineRequireObj().toContain = function() { ... };
```

somthing like a

```
getJasmineRequireObj().toNotContain = function() { ... };
```

?

> If not, how to add an extension or plugin to deliver this feature also
>   to our community of developers?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can use `not`:

```
getJasmineRequireObj().not.toContain
```

---

This example is from [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matchers):

```
describe("The 'toBe' matcher compares with ===", function() {
```

> #### Matchers
>
> Each matcher implements a boolean comparison between the actual value and the expected value. It is responsible for reporting to Jasmine if the expectation is true or false. Jasmine will then pass or fail the spec.

```
    it("and has a positive case", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
```

> Any matcher can evaluate to a negative assertion by chaining the call to `expect` with a `not` before calling the matcher.

```
    it("and can have a negative case", function() {
        expect(false).not.toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Check below code which will be hwlpful, also documentation 
 here https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

```
it("also works for finding a substring", function() {
  var a = "foo bar baz";

  expect(a).toContain("bar");
  expect(a).not.toContain("quux");
});
```